# Gridview hyperlink issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, query-string, aspxgridview

I have two pages **default.aspx** which has a `grdiview`. This `gridview` has two columns one is the Id number and the other the `hyperlink` of the path of the videos saved in a folder.
I have another page **videos.aspx**, which accepts a mp4url string to play the videos from the `hyperlink` clicked on the default page.
Now how do I send this url of the hyperlink clicked to this videos page?

### default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadData();
    }
}

//load data from database into gridview
 private void LoadData()
 {
     //code to load the data here
 }
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //code to upload video here. 
      //Store file details into database if upload successful
      if (blSucces)
      {
          Updatefileinfo(filename, FilePath + filename);
      }
 }
  // I want to send the strpath which is (FilePath + filename) to videos.aspx
  private void Updatefileinfo(string strfilename, string strPath)
  { 
     //code here
  }
```

Here is the template field of gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="List of Files" HeaderStyle-Width="50%">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Eval("filenameName") %>'
        </asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

What I want to do is add videos.aspx first to the navigateurl field in the beginning (perhaps I could use string.format, but then how do I recieve that in videos.aspx)

And in the videos.aspx
I should recieve only the strPath

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VideoPlayer1.Mp4Url = //file path here
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Eval("filenameName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%#String.Format("~/videos.aspx?videoPath={0}", Eval("VideoPath"))%>'>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

and in videos.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var path = Request.QueryString["videoPath"];
    VideoPlayer1.Mp4Url = path;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a parser error on the line  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server"

Comment: It says the server tag is not well formed

Comment: I'm getting this error 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'VideoPath'.

Comment: you could change "VideoPath" to what your gridview data source column video path holder... make sense?

Comment: Thanks for that. I wish I could have accepted both answers. I cant up vote either. On behalf of me up vote the other ans, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can use query string to pass the information from one page to another.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="List of Files" HeaderStyle-Width="50%">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server" 
             Text='<%# Eval("filenameName") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "video.aspx?v=" + Eval("VideoPath").ToString() %>'
        </asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and on video.aspx in page load access the video url as below

```
var vPath = Request.QueryString["v"];
VideoPlayer1.Mp4Url = vPath;
```

Comment: I'm getting a parser error on the line  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server"

Comment: It says the server tag is not well formed. How can this be solved?

Comment: There was a > missing. Now it says DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'VideoPath'. I need to add a eval for this?

Comment: you could change VideoPath to what your data source column is.. make sense?

Comment: Yeah it does! I just managed to do it adn you commented! Thanks :)

Comment: VideoPath is just a colum nname that i assumed you would have :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Target="_blank" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Eval("filenameName") %>'
    </asp:HyperLink>
```

you can use

```
<a href="videos.aspx?fname=<%#  Eval("filenameName")%>" target="_blank"><%# Eval("filenameName")%></a>
```

and in videos.aspx.cs file use this

```
String fname=Request.QueryString["fname"].toString();
VideoPlayer1.Mp4Url =fname;
```